# iPhone A13 Bionic breaks Streaming SDK (encoding)

Tags: ios, video-streaming, streaming, hardware, video-encoding

I'm not sure where to head for this problem, so I'm asking here, maybe someone has experience with streaming SDKs for iOS.

We are a small company and we have an app that uses a proprietary Streaming SDK that our company has bought from another company a while ago (~4 years, we just inherited an app with this library recently). The library is used so that users can livestream themselves to the other users of the app. This functionality has been working fine on all iOS devices, until we got some reports form users that they can't stream on iPhone 11, 11 Pro and 11 Pro Max devices.

Today, our team finally got our hands on an iPhone 11, so we tried debugging the streaming library to see whats going on. It turns out the AudioEncoder of the library is reaching its "failed" state at the beginning of the stream and stopping the whole stream.

Before even getting our hands on a new device I suspected that the new CPU must be messing up some part of the audio/video encoding, and turns out I was correct.

Unfortunately, we do not have any contact (nor support) with the company that created this library, I'm pretty sure they don't exist any more, and besides some headers, the rest of the SDK is packaged in a .a file so we can't dig into the code to fix it.

My questions are:

1. If anyone who has developed any streaming libraries has faced any
   similar issued with the new iPhones, and if you can point us on what
   the problem is and how we could fix it and
2. Some streaming library
       recommendations, preferably open source ones this time, so we don't
       end back in such a situation again in 5 years.

Answer (score 3):

Lucas,

We create [Larix SDK for mobile streaming](https://softvelum.com/larix/). From our experience, the SDK maintainer's main responsibility is not just develop new features, but maintain all the old and new OS and hardware releases. Every now and then some new system release may change APIs and add new restrictions so keeping app up-to date is critical in long-term.

Regarding iPhone 11 - there were no changes on those models in regard to audio, this is a library issue rather than the platform.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insights! Could you think of any reason why “our” library Works on all iPhone devices up to A13 devices on the software side? If nothing changed, there must be something else. I’ll take a look at your service, since I’m looking into alternative streaming libraries. I’m pretty sure we won’t be able to fix this without access to the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't speak for other solutions. I just know that every major release of iOS makes our mobile developers put everything aside and double-test our apps against it to make sure nothing has broken :)

Comment: We managed to get our hands on the source code, and it turns out that the SDK is setting the audio sample rate to 44100, and then checking the actual value, but on iPhone 11 and up, the call to AVAudioSession.shared.setPreferredSampleRate still keep the sample rate to 48000. I’ll probably post another question on SO about this “new” problem

Comment: Right, setPreferredSampleRate sets the *preferred* rate which is not a guarantee, Also depending on chosen mic, you'll get different rate. You'll get a few surprises with Bluetooth interaction as well.